# THREE.js Apply multiple textures on same mesh or new mesh with a cloned geometry

Tags: three.js, textures

---

## SEE THE SOLUTION BELOW

---

I am really confused. The target i am trying to achieve is;

Use multiple textures on a loaded mesh.

I have searched multiple times and still i can see the similar questions but nothing helped me.

What i'v tried is (yet);

Created a new mesh with the target mesh's geometry and pushed to target object3d element. (Like a photoshop layer.)

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture(mapCanvas);
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.needsUpdate = true;

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: texture, transparent: true});

var targetMesh = book.children[0].children[1],
    newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(targetMesh.geometry, material);

book.children[0].children.push(newMesh);
```

Result, wrong geometry attributes, or am i missing something?.

[image: Wrong geometry and placement]

But i think it could be a easier solution like using multiple textures at the same time with a correct order.

Full code:

```
sampleImage.onload = function() {
    var mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    mapCanvas.width = sampleImage.width;
    mapCanvas.height = sampleImage.height;

    var ctx = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.translate(sampleImage.width / 2, sampleImage.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.translate(-sampleImage.width / 2, -sampleImage.height / 2);
    ctx.drawImage(sampleImage, 0, 0, sampleImage.width, sampleImage.height);


    var texture = new THREE.Texture(mapCanvas);
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: texture, transparent: true});

    var targetMesh = book.children[0].children[1],
        newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(targetMesh.geometry, material);

    book.children[0].children.push(newMesh);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with cloning.

Do not push directly to the mesh group using javascript array push.

use `.add` method.

```
book.children[0].add(newMesh);
```